# When will the Catalyst 11.4 driver be available?

Tags: 11.04, drivers, xorg, fglrx, ati

I've seen a lot of questions about unity performance . When is an official Ubuntu update for the proprietary ATI driver coming . People are saying this is improving unity performance a lot . Sorry but I'm new to Ubuntu and a little bit afraid to do this change myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add extra repository with new driver version (for AMD and NVidia cards):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
```

There is new version of AMD Catalsys driver during the build process (at leas at the moment). You can check it on that page:

https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates/+packages

I am not sure if it is these version - the numbers are different and I don't know the number schema but probably it will be the new version of Catalsysy drivers.

Comment: Hi , thanks for the answer . I have added the repository and I got an update , but its so small I don't think its the actual driver

Comment: Check these directory: http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fglrx-installer/. There is ` fglrx-installer_8.841.orig.tar.gz` but there is no corresponding packages. According to that page: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates/+buildjob/2526516 it should be build in 8 hours. I think you can check tomorrow (depending on your time zone (-: ) and probably there will be some new drivers.

Comment: sorry I didn't had time until now to reply. Your solution worked thanks

Comment: the RAM is now kind of high and the speed improvement is small :)